# App.config vs AppName.exe.config

Tags: c#

Will it hurt anything if the app.config file is copied into the same directory with the appName.exe.config (in the environment it is running, DEV, TEST, STAGE or PROD)? I am curious to know if the app.config is simply ignored when running the appName.exe and that the .exe only reads the appName.exe.config.

Comment: It will be ignored.

Comment: Nice...  This was posted before, but never clearing answered.  I know it says not to say thank you, but Thanks Han...   Moojjoo back to coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will get ignored automatically.